# Joining metrics of positive Ricci curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-curvature

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold such that there is a closed submanifold $S\subset M$ with a Riemannian metric $g_S$ given by the restriction of a Riemannian metric on $M$ satisfying $\mathrm{Ricci}_{g_S}(X) > 0,~\forall X\in \Gamma(TS).$ Assume that there is another Riemannian metric $\tilde g$ on $M$ such that $\mathrm{Ricci}_{\tilde g}(Y) >0,~\forall Y\in \Gamma(T(M\setminus S)).$ Is it possible to obtain from $g_S$ and $\tilde g$ a Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ with positive Ricci curvature?

What if $S$ is a $0$-dimensional manifold?

Comment: It follows from Hamilton's theorem that the statement is correct for compact $3$-manifolds (for $\dim=2$ it's obvious). Indeed Hamilton proved that the universal cover of a $3$-manifold $M$ with non-negative Ricci is either $S^3$ or $S^2\times \mathbb R$. In the first case $M$ admits a metric of positive Ricci curvature. In the second the metric $g$ on $\widetilde{M}$ splits, so $Ricci_g$ is zero in some direction at any point of $M$

Comment: What is exactly your question in case $S$ is 0-dimensional? If you mean having positive Ric at a point, and Ric is nonnegative everywhere, then the metric can be deformed to positive Ric everywhere by a result of Ehrlich.

Comment: Hi, @RenatoG.Bettiol, I am familiar with this result. The original question was more about how to glue two different metrics. Perhaps I am missing something but it seems that unity partition make a mess with the curvatures. So the question was more on this direction.

Comment: Hi, @L.F.Cavenaghi did you manage to answer this? I have a similar problem in mind.

Comment: Hi, @LucasL. I didn't. I don't recall why I was interested in it, but I suppose it was related to the "Deformation Conjecture." For instance, a paper by B. Wilking shows that some non-negatively curved manifolds have flat planes concentrated in totally geodesic tori. Nowadays, I think this is not overcome by metric gluing or deformation.